# How to use Clang as a library

Tags: clang, llvm, lexer

I am doing my dissertation and I have to parse and tokenize the source code into individual functions. For every function I would like to extract names of types, called function names and type casts. Is the clang the right tool for that kind of job? If yes how can i do this?

Below is a simple C function. With bold are the extracted items I want:

```
static char func1(unsigned int a, struct foo *b)
{
    int c = 0;
    struct bar *d;

    if (a == 0) {
        d = func2((int) a);
    } else {
        c = func3((struct bar *) b);
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Clang is the right tool to do this job.

You should take a look a [`libclang`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html).

You can find enough information on internet, but I personally can recommend two great articles:

[Parsing C++ in Python with Clang](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/07/03/parsing-c-in-python-with-clang) by Eli Bendersky

[Introduction to libclang](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-24-introduction-to-libclang.html) by Mike Ash

If you prefer to watch videos, then I can recommend to look at the presentation on `libclang` here: [2010 LLVM Developers' Meeting](http://llvm.org/devmtg/2010-11/), look for `libclang: Thinking Beyond the Compiler`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. After doing some reading of my own I came to clang's documentation. It is saying that you can use clang for different stages of compilation. If I am correct I am interested for the preprocessing stage and the parsing and semantic analysis stage. Those stages can be invoked using the -fsyntax-only flag. However using this flag clang does not return the AST file as said in the documentation. Any ideas? Am I missing some tools for example from llvm, thats why it doesnot generate the AST?

Comment: I can't say for sure about the purpose of `-fsyntax-only`, but I assume it's there for easier debugging and maybe for some static analysis, when we don't need to proceed after semantic analysis is done.

`libclang` covers everything you need, it is basically does everything until code generation, it includes preprocessing (#include's, C macros), lexing, parsing, and semantic analysis.

Comment: I got an idea from reading the articles you posted. I can understand that clang is a compiler but also they provide all of its individual components to create my own preprocessor tool which I can configure as I like using their libraries and functions? Because this is out of the scope of my project, is there soething which is ready to use?

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend [LibTooling](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html). If you only need Preprocessing, [PreprocessOnlyAction](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1PreprocessOnlyAction.html) is helpful. If information of Abstract Syntax Tree is needed, you better choose [ASTFrontendAction](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1ASTFrontendAction.html).